# Wavesurfer doesn't render if parent display:block

Tags: javascript, css, wavesurfer.js

I'm having a similar issue to the one highlighted here

https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/960

I have wavesurfer appearing in a React Component. If it's rendered with its parent display:block then everything is fine, however if it renders display:none, then later changed to display:block the wave does not render.  The actual 'wave' element still has the attribute display 'none'

Here is the wavesurfer code

```
this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: this.$waveform,
  waveColor: 'grey',
  progressColor: 'purple',
  backend: 'MediaElement',
  height: 80,
  width: '100%',
  plugins: [
    TimelinePlugin.create({
      container: '#wave-timeline',
    }),
    RegionPlugin.create({
      dragSelection: true,
      drag: false,
    }),
  ],
})
```

It's parent

```
    <div className={!isSceneMenuVisible ? 'hide' : 'show'}>
```

And the CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh..

Use `visibility: hidden` instead otherwise it can't get it's dimensions.

https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/910